# How to use Codeigntier4 and cURL to upload a large json file via an external api

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl

I am having a rather conceptual problem understanding how this is to work.  I have a large JSON file of about 20mb+ to upload to an external api using post.  I can understand how to do this with limited data of say an array of name and jobs (see below) but how would it be done with a larger 'JSON file' from a remote location (eg my desktop).  For example, would I need to select the file from my local desktop, upload it to my cloud server and then send it to a post api or can it go from local desktop direct to remote api?   Also, it is a JSON file I want to send and not just limited date like below.  Any pointers super appreciated.  I am using Codeigniter 4x.

```
    $data = array(
        'name' => 'Thomas',
        'job' => 'puntaro'
    );
    $payload = json_encode($data);
    $request = curl_init();
    $url ='https://reqres.in/api/users';  // just a fake api for now
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($request);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($response);
    print_r(json_decode($response)); // add ,true to change to array
    echo '</pre>';
    curl_close($request);
```

Comment: What is the error with your current approach?

Answer (score 0):

For one when you do an HTTPS request you ned to use:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

And you do not send post fields as JSON.

Two ways to make your post data.

```
$post = 'key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3';
$post = array('key1'=>value1,'key2'=>value2,'key3'=>'value3');
```

You may need to use a better CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER
This is my basic header.  I use an obscure UA because they will not be able to profile my UA.

```
$request = array();
$request[] = "Host: www.example.com";
$request[] = "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
$request[] = "User-Agent: MOT-V9mm/00.62 UP.Browser/6.2.3.4.c.1.123 (GUI) MMP/2.0";
$request[] = "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5";
$request[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
$request[] = "Cache-Control: no-cache";
$request[] = "Pragma: no-cache";
```

POST data is always sent a key=> value
And a file upload is different than a post data.

You need to know the key value to use.
While I doubt is then you could try to post data like this.

```
$postdata = array('keyname'=>$payload);
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata );
```

If you really think you are supposed to make a post, then I have alot of trouble shooting tips.

I would reasonably think you'd need to do a file upload.

[PHP curl_file_create](https://www.php.net/manual/en/curlfile.construct.php)

UPDATE

> I have a few post fields that require key=>value but I also have a
> large json file. Is it possible to send at the same time?

Try the CURLFile class.

```
$upload= new CURLFile($filename); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ['upload' => $upload]);
```

Or add $upload to the array with you other post key - value fields.

Comment: Thank you @misunderstood.  I have a few post fields that require key=>value but I also have a large json file.  Is it possible to send at the same time?

Comment: @spreaderman Sure.  See the update in my answer.